# How to show the full result of the query in SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to see the query used to create the table `DOCTORS` in SQL Developer with

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'DOCTORS')
FROM dual;
```

Then it shows only part of the query.

```
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','DOCTORS')                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "C##AKIRA"."DOCTORS" 
   (    "CODED" NUMBER(2,0),  
    "NAMED" VARCHA
```

I suspect this is due to some displaying setting. Could you please elaborate on how to show the full result?

```
-- Drop tables if they already exist
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE works_in';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
            RAISE;
        END IF;
END;
/

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE depends';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
            RAISE;
        END IF;
END;
/

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE wards';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
            RAISE;
        END IF;
END;
/

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE doctors';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
            RAISE;
        END IF;
END;
/

-- Create the doctors database
CREATE TABLE doctors (
    coded       NUMBER(2),
    named       VARCHAR2(15),
    speciald    NUMBER(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (coded)
);

CREATE TABLE wards (
    codew       NUMBER(2),
    namew       VARCHAR2(15),
    coded       NUMBER(2),
    PRIMARY KEY(codew),
    FOREIGN KEY (coded) REFERENCES doctors (coded)
);

CREATE TABLE works_in (
    coded       NUMBER(2),
    codew       NUMBER(2),
    datewi      DATE,
    hourcount   NUMBER(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (coded, codew, datewi),
    FOREIGN KEY (coded) REFERENCES doctors (coded),
    FOREIGN KEY (codew) REFERENCES wards (codew)
);

CREATE TABLE depends (
    codew_parent        NUMBER(2),
    codew_child         NUMBER(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (codew_parent, codew_child),
    FOREIGN KEY (codew_parent) REFERENCES wards (codew),
    FOREIGN KEY (codew_child) REFERENCES wards (codew)
);

-- Show the schema of a table
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'DOCTORS')
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Note you can also just say, DDL doctors .. that will get you the ddl for your table

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I tried `DDL doctors`, but it returns an error `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`.

Comment: You need a recent copy of sqldev, say 18.1 or higher, then run using the script (f5) method

Comment: Thank you so much @thatjeffsmith. It works well on my SQL Developer, but not Datagrip.

Comment: Right, it's a client command, not a database command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try putting

```
set long 1000000 longc 100000 pages 10000
```

before the select dbms_metadata....
It tells sqldev (and sqlplus/sqlcl also) to fetch 1MB of data and not put headers until after 10000 lines